# Heroku Deployment issues with weird Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I'm a newbie and I am having issues deploying my code onto Heroku.  I keep getting this error response.  It looks like a JS Parse Error, which I have no idea what it could be.   ANY help would be amazing.  Thanks!

I was successfully able to upload my previous application.  I worry that it was because I tried to install some JQUERY plugins and it deleted the info inside my JS folder

```
    Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2013-12-10T02:45:51.431542 #852]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_63a972cd-66ca-44b3-a93f-1478701014b8/public/assets/City View-7537eeed9ac680ad1956b2e52f4c84d0.JPG
       I, [2013-12-10T02:45:51.440831 #852]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_63a972cd-66ca-44b3-a93f-1478701014b8/public/assets/Colorado Mountains-4ccd1ab828df293099a6548b5a6e8bfe.JPG
       I, [2013-12-10T02:45:51.446787 #852]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_63a972cd-66ca-44b3-a93f-1478701014b8/public/assets/Island-21840c8c6f0a45aa2a1a26aaeaded68f.JPG
       I, [2013-12-10T02:45:51.456045 #852]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_63a972cd-66ca-44b3-a93f-1478701014b8/public/assets/NOLA-c7734de5b96452884f62c917a6c973f4.JPG
       I, [2013-12-10T02:45:51.465607 #852]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_63a972cd-66ca-44b3-a93f-1478701014b8/public/assets/Sunset Surf-c0b9df5142538dbeb16ce1fc6d28b0f7.JPG
       rake aborted!
       Unexpected token: operator (<) (line: 12505, col: 0, pos: 353374)
       Error
       at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20131210-852-vt66tc.js:2357:10748)
       at js_error (/tmp/execjs20131210-852-vt66tc.js:2357:10967)
       at croak (/tmp/execjs20131210-852-vt66tc.js:2357:19192)
       at token_error (/tmp/execjs20131210-852-vt66tc.js:2357:19329)
       at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20131210-852-vt66tc.js:2357:19417)
       at /tmp/execjs20131210-852-vt66tc.js:2357:27609
       at /tmp/execjs20131210-852-vt66tc.js:2357:30102
       at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20131210-852-vt66tc.js:2357:30860)
       at /tmp/execjs20131210-852-vt66tc.js:2357:30952
       at /tmp/execjs20131210-852-vt66tc.js:2357:31395
       (in /tmp/build_63a972cd-66ca-44b3-a93f-1478701014b8/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)/tmp/build_63a972cd-66ca-44b3-a93f-1478701014
```

Comment: `Unexpected token:` is a Javascript error - you get it when you're trying to call an object / element which doesn't exist

Comment: It looks like your error is on `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` - can you post it?

Comment: The heroku deploy is failing when it tries to compile your application.js file.  Look for an error in the javascript, or post the file contents for more help.